# How to integrate the jquery custom scrollbar to Tinymce editor

Tags: jquery, html

I need your help. i have tried and implement the scroll bar but it only takes effect when the page load but when i wrote conent and press enter it takeI need to integrate the jquery custom scroll bar to TinyMCE Editor content area.Have any body idea about this ? If yes then please guid me how to integrate it.

I would appreciate any kind of help?